# Development VPS where environment (Ruby/Rails, JavaScript/Node.js etc) is pre-installed?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, node.js

Until now I'm setting up my own development environment with Vagrant/VirtualBox/Chef (Ruby).

I wonder if there is a hosting company that provides pre-configured VPS for...

- Ruby/Rails
- Javascript/Node

...letting me just choose what I want to have installed and also which linux packages I would like to install in each VPS.

Are there hosting companies providing this?

Comment: Never- I'm surprised that you ask this question since your previous questions clearly show that you've used Heroku on several occasions.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has "experimental" node.js support (and obviously Rails).

http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/4/28/node_js_support_experimental/

Comment: But Heroku is mainly for production use. I want to have a VPS I can develop in and then just push it to Heroku.

Comment: If you're considering a VPS anyway, what's the difference? If you want something more local, just for development, I like Ubuntu running in VirtualBox for node.js experimentation.